# A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a Navigation RouteFuction which will navigate between screens, and i found this kind of error in `RouterFcatory` function. Code is below. thanks

```
RouteFactory _routes() {
    return (settings) {
      final Map<String, dynamic> arguments = settings.arguments;
      Widget screen;
      switch (settings.name) {
        case LocationsRoute:`
          screen = Locations();
          break;
        case LocationDetailRout:
        screen = LocationDetail(arguments['id']);
      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: Mention your error clearly, and seems like there is a is match, between data types.

Comment: What is `settings.arguments`?

Comment: use **final Map<String, dynamic> arguments = Map<String, dynamic>.from(settings.arguments);** maybe helpful

Answer (score 0):

change

```
final Map<String, dynamic> arguments = settings.arguments;
```

to

```
final arguments = settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>;
```